# Ignored JUnit Assert method calls executed outside of main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit, concurrency

Constant scheduling of small tasks is the core concept of my application. Most methods are static and come in two forms: public method `executeSomeAction(Some param)`, which schedules execution of its private counterpart: `ThreadPool.execute(() -> someAction())`.

The things is - most methods are cut into small tasks that can be executed concurrently, and while they do pass separate function calls to the ThreadPool, I'd rather keep these "smaller" methods static and private. Needless to say, it's not as easy to write a test that checks if a static method was executed, as it would be with an object. I'm satisfied with the performance and the overall application structure (focusing on immutable data and multithreaded execution), but I have no idea how to write unit tests for some of this stuff.

For example - I recently realized that even the core methods tests... always pass due to being executed on child threads rather than the main test's one:

```
@Test
public void shouldExecutePassedRunnables() {
    final int expectedCounterValue = 1;
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    ThreadPool.execute(() -> {
        counter.getAndIncrement();
        ThreadPool.execute(() -> Assert.assertEquals(Tests.shouldSucceed("Counter incrementation"),
                counter.get(), expectedCounterValue));
    });
    ThreadPool.awaitTermination(Tests.DEFAULT_DELAY);
}
```

Hell, I even put Assert.fail() and debug logs all over the executed functions just to make sure I'm right. It just ignores Assert calls in other threads.

Mockito doesn't help either. When I want to check if a method has been called on an object with a spy, it ignores the calls made in other threads. Which will be the ONLY calls, mostly.

Since I'd rather test the public API than being forced to make 100% of my methods public (or even package-private, for that matter), I need a way to make sure that all of the tasks scheduled to the ThreadPool were executed and PROPERLY handled. Is there a way to do that? Or is there another library (or some pretty stable JUnit extension) I could look into?

Comment: This is a difficult problem.  Whole books have been written on this stuff.  I'd say it's way too broad to be answered well on Stack Overflow (although I'm sure some people will try).

Comment: But whatever you do ... don't run assertions in multiple threads.  All of  your assertions (including JUnit `Assert` methods and Mockito `verify` calls) should be in the main thread of the test.  Otherwise, the outcomes of your tests aren't well-defined.

Comment: have a look at this [Test thread safety]- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076265/testing-debugging/junit-best-practices.html

Comment: @David, I figured that one out the hard way, but it's not always possible to await for termination and hope for the best. Originally, I want to specifically test that one task triggers another and both get executed. The test I included could be changed to call Assert::assertEquals after ThreadPool::awaitTermination, but it doesn't change the fact that most `verify` calls do not "see" executions of the methods done by other threads and sometimes just executing a runnable is not enough. `assert`/`verify` honored by on all threads would be ideal.

Comment: Then use a Mockito `Answer` in the mocks used by your threads, to set up some kind of state that you can check from your main thread.

Comment: I don't think `Answer` solves the problem of mostly static methods that return null and just schedule execution of one or more connected actions. Especially if the called actions chain even more scheduled executions (which is often desired, especially when something can be done concurrently).

Comment: By the way, I just made sure that `verify` - even called on the main thread - doesn't seem to count method calls from other threads. I don't feel like adding some kind of method execution counter on every method just to have most of my code covered by tests, to be honest. I wonder if making a small testing framework or trying to modify JUnit code/behavior would be worth the time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about your application to be able to answer that.  Again, your question seems far too broad for this site.

Comment: The problem is that assert and fail calls only succeed if they're performed from the main test thread. As far as a solution, check out [ConcurrentUnit](https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit/).